# Beautification of the print output of the console

Tags: python, printing, console

I have an output in the Console. Unfortunately the texts are of different length and therefore looks very shifted. Is there an option that writes the texts below each other, no matter how many characters are in front of them, so that the output looks the way I want it to look?

I would not like to use another library for this.

```py
print(65 * '_')
print('algorithm\t\t\tsil\t\tdbs')

results =  ['Agglomerative Clustering', 0.8665, 0.4200]
formatter_result = ("{:9s}\t\t{:.4f}\t{:.4f}")
print(formatter_result.format(*results))
    
results = ['k-Means', 0.9865, 0.1200]
formatter_result = ("{:9s}\t\t{:.4f}\t{:.4f}")
print(formatter_result.format(*results))

print(65 * '_')
```

What I have

```py
_________________________________________________________________
algorithm           sil     dbs
Agglomerative Clustering        0.8665  0.4200
k-Means         0.9865  0.1200
_________________________________________________________________
```

What I want

```py
_________________________________________________________________
algorithm                    sil        dbs
Agglomerative Clustering     0.8665     0.4200
k-Means                      0.9865     0.1200
_________________________________________________________________
```

I looked at [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data) and tried it, but dosen't work for me

```py
print(65 * '_')

heading = ['algorithm', 'sil', 'dbs']
result1 =  ['Agglomerative Clustering', 0.8665, 0.4200]
result2 = ['k-Means', 0.9865, 0.1200]
ab = np.array([heading, result1, result2])
for row in ab:
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))
    



print(65 * '_')
_________________________________________________________________
           algorithm                  sil                  dbs
Agglomerative Clustering               0.8665                 0.42
             k-Means               0.9865                 0.12
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Comment: @MikeScotty please see my edit. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `{:<20}`, this means 20 spaces with left alignment. There is also `{:^20}` - center alignment and `{:>20}`- right alignment.

To combine it with `float` notation e.g. `.4f` just add to it: `{:<20.4f}`

Try this:

```py
print(65 * "_")
formatter_result = "{:<35} {:<20} {:<20}"
formatter_result_f = "{:<35} {:<20.4f} {:<20.4f}"
print(formatter_result.format(*["algorithm", "sil", "dbs"]))
results = ["Agglomerative Clustering", 0.8665, 0.4200]
print(formatter_result_f.format(*results))
results = ["k-Means", 0.9865, 0.1200]
print(formatter_result_f.format(*results))
print(65 * "_")
```

Result:

```
_________________________________________________________________
algorithm                           sil                  dbs                 
Agglomerative Clustering            0.8665               0.4200              
k-Means                             0.9865               0.1200              
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1):

hi so you have to remove some \t cause they create tabs and you can remove them one by one to find one that you prefer

print('for example, this is a tab \t\t\t there is going to be space between them')

print('for example, there is no tab here and it is going to be next to each other')